# AWS Amplify datastore query and sort by date

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

playing around with amplify and datastore with nodejs and react.

I have model for `message`

```
type Message
@model
@auth(rules: [{allow: owner, operations: [read, create, update, delete]}]) {
  id: ID!
  content: String!
}
```

I want to fetch all messages and sort in desceding order.
What I am trying to do

```
    const messages = await DataStore.query(Message, Predicates.ALL, {
      sort: s => s.createdAt(SortDirection.DESCENDING),
      page: 0,
      limit: 20
    });
```

My solution doesn't seem to affect the sorting at all. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The createdAt method takes in a string either "ASCENDING" or "DESCENDING"

Try this:

```
const messages = await DataStore.query(Message, Predicates.ALL, {
      sort: s => s.createdAt("DESCENDING"),
      page: 0,
      limit: 20
    });
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).